# I keep getting the error List assignment index out of range, why? (Python)

Tags: python

Problem:
`Calculate the mean and standard deviation of a tightly clustered set of 1000 initial conditions as a function of iteration number. The bunch of initial conditions should be Gaussian distributed about x = 0.3 with a standard deviation of 10-3`

The code I wrote:

```
from numpy import *

def IterateMap(x,r,n):
    for i in xrange(n):
        x = r * x * (1.0 - x)
    return x

output = "data"
nIterations = 1000
r = 4.0
x0 = 0.3
delta = 0.00005

L = []

for i in xrange(nIterations):
    x = x0
    x = IterateMap(x,r,1)
    L[i] = x
    x0 = x0 + delta

A = array(L)

print 'mean: ', mean(A)
```

So what my code is supposed to do is to take an initial value for x (x0) and call the IterateMap function and return a new value of x and place it in a list(L) then x0 changes to a new value, and this process continues for 1000 times. I get the error "list assignment index out of range". Also, do you think I'm following the problem correctly?

Comment: Include the *full* traceback so we don't have to guess where your error occurs, please.

Comment: `L = []` and then you try to do `L[i] = x`, there are no elements in the list. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python lists do not automatically grow when you address indices beyond it's current size. You created an empty list, so you cannot address *any* index in it.

Use `.append()` to add new values to the end of the list:

```
L.append(x)
```

Alternatively, you'd have to create a list that can hold all the indices you want to generate instead, by pre-filling it with None or another default value:

```
L = [None for _ in xrange(nIterations)]
```

Comment: Thanks, btw, I'm now getting an index out of bounds error when I set my nIterations to 1000. However, if I use 500 or 700 it works. Any ideas as to what may cause this?

Comment: @Randy: because whatever index you are using at the time of the indexerror is not part of the list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
L = [] # the list is empty!

for i in xrange(nIterations):
    ...
    L[i] = x
```

To fix, replace `L[i] = x` with `L.append(x)`.